# Integration test with Mockito doesn't get coverage even when it enters the else statement

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to do some integration tests on Rest API with Mockito in Spring Boot. Even though that my code in the else statement gets tested still it does not give me coverage. I added some  **System.out.println()** to make sure that the code gets executed in the **else** statment. As I looked into the debug console, the **System.out.println()** outputs in the console, the else statment gets executed but still the code doesn't get detected by the coverage. Only the if statement gets detected. I removed the if-else statement to go directly in the code that was in the else statement but still doesn't get detected. I assume that this could be because I am using **forEach** or **Set<>.**

The Unit Test Class:

```
@WebMvcTest(AuthController.class)
public class AuthControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @MockBean
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @MockBean
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @MockBean
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    @MockBean
    PasswordEncoder encoder;
    @MockBean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Test
    public void testRegisterUser() throws Exception{
        List <Role> listRoles = new ArrayList<>();
        listRoles.add(new Role(ERole.ROLE_USER));
        listRoles.add(new Role(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR));
        listRoles.add(new Role(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN));
        Mockito.when(roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.ofNullable(listRoles.get(0)));
        Mockito.when(roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.ofNullable(listRoles.get(1)));
        Mockito.when(roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.ofNullable(listRoles.get(2)));
        Set<String> currentRoles = new HashSet<>();
        currentRoles.add("admin");
        currentRoles.add("mod");
        currentRoles.add("user");

        SignupRequest signupRequest = new SignupRequest();
        signupRequest.setUsername("test");
        signupRequest.setEmail("test");
        signupRequest.setPassword("12341234");
        signupRequest.setRole(currentRoles);

        User user = new User(signupRequest.getUsername(),
                signupRequest.getEmail(),
                encoder.encode(signupRequest.getPassword()));

        Set<String> strRoles = signupRequest.getRole();
        System.out.println(strRoles);
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
            System.out.println("enters if");
        }
        else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                    case "admin":
                        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(adminRole);
                        System.out.println("enters case admin");
                        break;
                    case "mod":
                        Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(modRole);
                        System.out.println("enters case mod");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                        roles.add(userRole);
                        System.out.println("enters case user");
                }
            });
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        String url = "/auth/signup";

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post(url).contentType("application/json")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user))).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        System.out.println(status);
    }


}
```

The AuthController Class:

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
        AlreadyExistsError AlreadyExistsError = new AlreadyExistsError();

        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            AlreadyExistsError.setUserAlreadyExists(true);
        }
        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            AlreadyExistsError.setEmailAlreadyExists(true);
        }

        if (AlreadyExistsError.hasAnyErrors()){
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(AlreadyExistsError);
        }

        // Create new user's account
        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(), 
                             signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                             encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        }
        else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                case "admin":
                    Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(adminRole);

                    break;
                case "mod":
                    Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(modRole);

                    break;
                default:
                    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/users")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> searchUser(@RequestParam String username){
        return  userRepository.findByUsernameContaining(username);
    }
```

How my coverage looks like:

[image: Coverage]

Comment: That you've copied a (rather) large chunk of your tested code into the test method should be a warning signal for you. A test method should only test one condition, that's all. So you should write one test dedicated test method for each role, one for when no role is given and one when multiple roles are given.

Comment: I made seperate unit-tests for each condition for strRoles==null, for admin, for mod and for user, but I still get no coverage for the last 3.

Comment: Then you either made a mistake in each test or you didn't run the test to get their coverage report (and you only look at the coverage report of a test that doesn't enter the 'else' branch). Have you tried debugging your controller while you run one of the new test methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I was passing `.content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user)))` instead of `.content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(signuprequest)))` because the `@RequestBody` is `SignupRequest` not `User`.

Answer (score 1):

Your println-calls only tell you that you are executing the three switch cases in the else block *in your test*, but not in the actual Controller.

It absolutley does not make any sense to have most of the controller code in the test. This does not seem to accomplish anything. The coverage tells you that the way you are calling the Controller at the end of your test only triggers the case for `strRoles` being `null`.